# LaTeX3: \file_if_exist:nTF & complete path to the file found

Tags: latex3, file-lookup

`\file_if_exist:nTF` searches the TeX/LaTeX input path for the filename given as an argument. Now I am looking for a way to get hands on the complete path to the file, in case it was found. From the LaTeX2e command `\IfFileExists` I know that it stores the path to the file in the macro `\@filef@und`. I wonder if there is a LaTeX3 counterpart to `\@filef@und`. If not, I kindly ask the LaTeX3 developers to provide a such, because it may come in handy in certain programming tasks.

Comment: Currently, there is no public version of this information: the method of using `\@filef@und` is clearly an abuse of `\IfFileExist`. I wonder if you can give a good example where the path is needed outside of the file loading routine?

Comment: @Joseph: First of all, `\IfFileExist` and `\file_if_exist:nTF` are not file loading but file locating routines. Hence, it is up to the user (or package author) to decide what to do with the information gained. One possible use is related to the `latex->dvips->ps2pdf` workflow. A LaTeX package may contain raw Postscript file reading/writing operators in its code. LaTeX and Ghostscript don't necessarily evaluate the same search paths and the Ghostscript search path cannot be set from within the LaTeX document. (to be continued)

Comment: @Joseph: (continued) For convenience, in order to unburden the potential package user from manipulating Ghostscript search paths, it would be nice if the LaTeX search path provided by the user in his document could be used to find a file. The path to the file could then be inserted into the Postscript code by the LaTeX package.

Comment: @Alexander: Interesting example, which is outside of my range of experience. I'll see what makes most sense in terms of a structured interface here. Perhaps `\file_get_path:nN`, returning `\q_no_value` if the file is not found?

Comment: @Joseph: This would be really great. Thank you for taking this into consideration!

Comment: @Joseph: Yet another, unrelated to Postscript, example: Driver specific file reading primitives, such as `\pdfximage` or `\XeTeXpdffile`, usually do not evaluate LaTeX `\input@path`. Package writers who wish to apply those primitives will have to either implement their own file finding routines or resort to `\@filef@und` abuse (as in `graphics.sty`, BTW!) if they want to make use of `\input@path`. Therefore, something like `\file_get_path:nN` would be highly welcome.

Comment: @Alexander: Things like drivers are something that we'd hope will be covered over time by kernel-level material, which means 'day to day' LaTeX3 programmers should not need to worry about this type of issue. However, I can see the need on top of LaTeX2e, and we will need something internally, of course!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have just added to the development version of `expl3` a function `\file_add_path:nN`:

```
\file_add_path:nN { <file name> } <tl var>
```

which will result in the  (storage macro) containing either:

1. The fully-qualified file name, if the file is found on the LaTeX path or
2. Nothing at all (*i.e.* an empty macro) if the file is not found

I've also adjusted the other file code to make use of this. The idea is that you can save doing the file test if you know you'll need to use the path, by doing

```
\file_add_path:nN { filename } \l_my_tl
\tl_if_empty:NTF \l_my_tl
  { No-file-found-code }
  { File-found-code }
```

but unlike LaTeX2e this is documented and therefore officially-supported.

This will go to CTAN with the next update: let me know if this is urgent (I do the releases 'from time to time').

Comment: Perfect! Thank you a lot! There is no rush on updating, though. I have just another suggestion regarding the LaTeX search path. It would be nice to have two variants of the existing `\file_path_include:n` macro, one that adds a new path on the left and another one to add it on the right side of the existing search path, in order to have control over the priority. It's only for completeness and not essential at all. Thank you once more.